# Birt Reports - Don't generate an empty report

Tags: birt

I have several Birt Reports that I am trying to set up to run on a cron job that will email pdfs of the reports every morning.  Everything is working fine as far as the generation and emailing goes; the only issue I am stuck with is this: if there is nothing to report, a pdf with just the report title is generated and emailed (a blank report, basically).  I'd like to stop this report from being generated at all, so i can skip the emailing, if the pdf file does not exist.

I have been all over Google for two days now, and the closest I can find is this: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/458779/ in which someone was trying to solve a similar problem and received a push in the right direction, but not a complete solution.

It appears as if this can be done during the `beforerender` script... but how?
I know I need to:

1. set a persistent global variable in the `oncreate` if there is indeed data to report.
2. get the persistent global variable in the `beforerender` script.
3. send the magic `don't generate report` command.

I'm doing all of generating and emailing from a php script, not Java, so I can't send commands like  `IEngineTask.cancel()` (or can I???)

Yes, I know I can make a row in the report that says "No data to report", but that's not what my users want.

And yes, I could query the database outside of the report to determine if there is valid data to report or not, but i'd prefer not to.

And maybe I could even open and read the pdf, programmatically to see if there is anything  there, but that sounds like more of a hassle than it's worth...

So, how do I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is a little bit late, but I'm doing it like this in a framework that is working for hundreds of reports, probably it could be simplified for a single report:
Note that all the code is written from memory (not copied from our framework), so maybe it contains some errors.

Add an external Javascript file `myframework.js` to your report.

In this file, define an object `myframework` like this:

```
if (myframework == undefined) {
    myframework = {
        dataFound: false,
        afterReport: function() {
            // Write it to the appContext.
            // Using Java, you could read it after the
            // runAndRenderTask is done.
            reportContext.getAppContext().put("dataFound", this.dataFound);
            // But since you probably cannot the context
            // (don't like coding Java?), the report has to
            // tell it to he world some other way...
            var txt = "dataFound=" + (dataFound? "true": "false");
            var fw = new java.io.FileWriter("c:\\reportcontext.out");
            fw.write(txt);
            fw.close();
        }
    };
}
```

Add the JS file to your report's resources.

In your report, at a place where you decide that the report has found something (e.g. typically in a data set's `onFetch` event), tell the framework so by calling

```
myframework.dataFound = true;
```

In the reports's `afterFactory` or `afterRender` event, call

```
myframework.afterReport();
```

Then your report should create an output file c:\reportcontext.out which contains the information you need.